# Approach for Modifying value in View Controller A from View Controller B

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

I am trying to avoid the screen off when users leave iPhone in the car for long time for the navigation purpose.

Based on my research, the approach include

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

I believe this piece of code will sit in AppDelegate.m.

So, how can i set the Bool value from SettingViewController?  Basically, what is the best approach for setting a value from other class? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not necessary in this case to write this piece of code to sit in AppDelegate.

Comment: @Zaid Pathan you are right, you can put your piece of code any controller as per your requirement, and you can enable,disable any time too.

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya Yes thanks Jiga,  and It is recommended to write a helper function that will get Bool as parameter and you can call it when needed.

Comment: So, basically, it is not necessary to write this piece of code in AppDelegate anyway right? Just put it into the setting controller and it will take the same function?

Comment: Yes, You can write this code anywhere. It will take effect and enable/disable idle screen timer.

Comment: @DavidJohnson cheers man